# How to get waveform of mp3 or audio file?

Tags: android, waveform

I am making app like mp3 cutter. I want to know how to show waveform of audio in android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) for an implementation of a waveform and some inspiration on how to cut audio.

Comment: Thanks, Its very useful code.